# NEST MultiGet search all types possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have got unique document ids (across all types) and I would like to check which document already exists in elasticsearch index. I try to search

```
  var duplicateCheck = _elasticClient
                    .MultiGet(m => m.GetMany<object>(notices.Select(s => s.Id)).Fields("Id"));
```

but it returns wrong result - every document has set found property to false.

**update**
there is workaround here

```
 var exisitngDocIds = _elasticClient.Search<ZPBase>(s => s
                        .AllTypes()
                        .Query(q => q.Ids(notices.Select(z=>z.Id)))
                        .Fields("Id")
                        .Take(notices.Count)
                    );

notices = notices.Where(q => !exisitngDocIds.Hits.Any(s => s.Id == q.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Multi Get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html#mget-type) documentation I realized that you can use something similar to the following code to solve your problem:

```
var response = _elasticClient.MultiGet(m => m
                    .Index(MyIndex)
                    .Type("")
                    .GetMany<ZPBase>(noticeIds));
```

Note the empty string passed as the `Type`.